# Typechecking in Kotlin with interface and class

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface named Identifiable.

```
interface Identifiable {
    var id: String`
}
```

And I have a few classes that adhere to this interface. For example

```
class ArticleShrinked(val category: ArticleCategory,
                      override var id: String,
                      val timestamp: Date) : Shrinkable, Identifiable, Indexable {

    override val order: String
        get() = "id"
}
```

And I have a function that takes an object that confirms to Identifiable and detects its class and does things based on class.

```
// There has to be a bettwe way to deal with this
fun setItem(item: Identifiable?) {
        val article: Article? = item as? Article
        if (article != null) {
            // do something with article
        }

        val shrinked: ArticleShrinked? = item as? ArticleShrinked
        if (shrinked != null) {
            // do something with shrinked
        }

        val bloated: ArticleBloated? = item as? ArticleBloated
        if (bloated != null) {
            // do something with bloated
        }

        val annotation: ArticleAnnotation? = item as? ArticleAnnotation
        if (annotation != null) {
            // do something with bloated
        }
}
```

Typechecking the normal way does not work here

```
if (item is Article)
```

and putting it in a switch statement also fails.

```
when (item) {

   is Article -> // do something

}
```

Even using `item as Any? as Article` does not work. Any idea how I can write my function more elegantly?

Comment: seems you need an abstract class rather than an interface

Comment: This seems like a good use case for a sealed class

Comment: I don't see why the `when` statement wouldn't work. How does it fail, as you described? Often, it's a code smell when you find yourself checking the type of a class to decide how to react, and you should be putting a method in the super type so each implementation can describe its own behavior. But sometimes this is impractical like if this class is doing something to the other items. If that is the case, sealed classes would be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin (and Java), it's not enough just to implement methods that have the same *signature* as those in an interface; in order to implement an interface in a way which the compiler will acknowledge, you have to specify that explicitly when you define your class.  Only then will you be implementing the right methods, and only then will the type system recognise the relationship.

So the `is` check does *not* ask “Does this object implement the right methods?”  It asks “Does this object descend from the right interface in the type hierarchy?”

In this case, `ArticleShrinked` implements the interfaces `Shrinkable`, `Identifiable`, and `Indexable` — but it does *not* implement `Article`.  So it is not a subtype of `Article`, and an `ArticleShrinked` object is not an `Article`, even if it might look like one.

That can be quite restrictive (especially if you want classes you didn't write to implement your interface, which is impossible).  But it's much safer.  Otherwise, you might find your own classes mistakenly implementing all sorts of interfaces, just because you coincidentally happened to choose the same method names.

Comment: perfect explanation, thanks! Guess that 'is' is not suitable as "instance of" works only on classes, not on interfaces, correct?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi `is` is just like Java's `instanceof`: it checks the type of an object.  So it can check an object against any type: that could be a simple class name, such as `String`; a type derived from it, such as `String?` or `List<*>`*; an interface, such as `CharSequence`; or a type derived from _that_, such as `CharSequence?`.  Try it and see!  (* Note that if a class is parameterised, the bare classname isn't a type, so `List` doesn't work.  However, due to type erasure you can't check for a particular type parameter; all you can do is use a wildcard.)

Answer (score 1):

A way could be to get rid of interfaces and use abstract classes in order to perform type checking at runtime. However you'll need to use inheritance between `Shrinkable`, `Indexable` and `Identifiable`. Then expect I would expect a generic as a parameter for your `setItem` function.

Something like:

```kotlin
abstract class Identifiable(val id: String)
    abstract class Indexable(id: String, val index: Int) : Identifiable(id)
    abstract class Shrinkable(id: String, index: Int, val shrink: Boolean) : Indexable(id, index)

    class ArticleShrinked(id: String, index: Int, shrink: Boolean) : Shrinkable(id, index, shrink)

    class ArticleBloated()

    class ArticleAnnotation()

    // There has to be a bettwe way to deal with this
    fun setItem(item: Any?) {
        item?.let {
            when (item) {
                is ArticleAnnotation -> {

                }
                is ArticleBloated -> {

                }
                is ArticleShrinked -> {

                }
                else -> {

                }
            }
        } ?: run {
            // is null
        }
    }
```